# MySQL 5.5: Efficient way to copy the same user information with different IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, join, insert, copy

In MySQL 5.5, assume we have the following MAIN table

```
Id  Name    Score
3   a   100
3   b   99
4   c   98
4   d   97
```

Also a SUB table:

```
Id  New_Id
3   1
3   1
4   2
4   2
```

The ideal output is OUTPUT table:

```
Id  Name    Score
3   a   100
3   b   99
4   c   98
4   d   97
1   a   100
1   b   99
2   c   98
2   d   97
```

The MySQL fiddle is available here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91c1cf/6

In the OUTPUT table,

we can see that the Id=1 shares the same information as Id =3. Similarly,

we can see that the Id=2 shares the same information as Id =4.

Is there any simple way such as "INSERT INTO...SELECT", "COPY", and "UPDATE" etc. that we can just copy the data from Id=3 to Id=1, and

copy the data from Id=4 to Id=2?

The following query does generate our ideal output, but the JOIN with the proper indexes is still painfully slow in our few hundreds millions rows.  The job even fails due to not sufficient RAM and /tmp folder space in the case of few billion rows.  We are upgrading our system from MySQL to somewhere more scab-able.  However, we need to make sure the MySQL system will be functional during the few months of the transit period.  Any 2 cents will be highly appreciated!

```
SELECT Id, Name, Score FROM MAIN

UNION

SELECT d.New_Id AS Id, c.Name, c.Score FROM MAIN c
RIGHT JOIN SUB d

ON c.Id = d.Id;
```

Comment: Any reason you're using `RIGHT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `INNER JOIN` rather than `RIGHT JOIN`, since you don't need the null rows that result from non-matching rows. You can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` to add these new rows to the table. And rather than using `UNION`, you can simply do two inserts into the new table:

```
INSERT INTO OUTPUT (id, name, score)
SELECT id, name, score
FROM MAIN;

INSERT INTO OUTPUT (id, name, score)
SELECT d.new_id, c.name, c.score
FROM MAIN AS c
JOIN SUB AS d ON c.id = d.id;
```

As long as you have indexes on the `id` columns in both input tables this should be as efficient as possible.

Finally, when doing large `UNION` queries, use `UNION ALL` if you know there are no duplicates that need to be merged. `UNION` by itself defaults to `UNION DISTINCT`, so it needs to create a temporary table to hold all the results to scan for duplicates.

Comment: Thanks!  1. I guess there is no way to escape from a JOIN here right?  2. So usually UNION ALL is going to be faster and more RAM efficient than UNION?

Comment: 1. Nope. That's the normal way to combine information from related rows in different tables. 2. Yes, because removing duplicates requires extra work.

Comment: Another question: will the efficiency from fast to slow is: (1) "INSERT a big INNER JOIN" > (2) "(SELECT * FROM) UNION ALL (a big INNER JOIN)" > (3) "(SELECT * FROM) UNION (a big INNER JOIN)"?

Comment: When you use `UNION`, the time taken is the time for each sub-query, plus the time needed to merge the results. If you use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION DISTINCT`, the merge time is negligible.

Comment: Is (1) "INSERT a big INNER JOIN" faster than (2) "(SELECT * FROM) UNION ALL (a big INNER JOIN)"?

Comment: I think it should be obvious that the first is faster. The expense of the big inner join is the same in both cases, and the second additionally does (select * from...).