# Insert million rows in the same table and update IDs in the copied rows based on the ID mapping information (MySQL, Python, sqlite3, sqlalchemy)

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Assume we have the following MAIN table in MySQL 5.5,

```
Id  Name    Score
3   a   100
3   b   99
4   c   98
4   d   97
```

Also there is an ID mapping in the SUB table:

```
Id  New_Id
3   1
3   1
4   2
4   2
```

We would like to copy the the rows in the MAIN table itself, if the Id in MAIN table shows up  in the SUB "mapping" table.  However, not only we would like to copy these rows, we would like to update these copied rows' "Id" into "New_Id".

The ideal output is OUTPUT table:

```
Id  Name    Score
3   a   100
3   b   99
4   c   98
4   d   97
1   a   100
1   b   99
2   c   98
2   d   97
```

Here Id 3 and 4 show up in the mapping, so copy these rows where Id = 3 and 4, then update these copied rows' "Id" into "New_Id" ('3' to '1', and '4' to '2') .

The MySQL fiddle is available here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91c1cf/6

The following 2 queries do generate our ideal output, but they are painfully slow in our few hundreds millions rows.  The job even fails due to not sufficient RAM and /tmp folder space in the case of few billion rows.  We are upgrading our system from MySQL to somewhere more scab-able.  However, we need to make sure the MySQL system will be functional during the few months of the transit period.  Any 2 cents and solutions in MySQL and Python (sqlite3, sqlalchemy, etc.) will be highly appreciated!

Query 1:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Score FROM MAIN

UNION

SELECT d.New_Id AS Id, c.Name, c.Score FROM MAIN c
RIGHT JOIN SUB d

ON c.Id = d.Id;
```

Query 2: (from here: [MySQL 5.5: Efficient way to copy the same user information with different IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885501/mysql-5-5-efficient-way-to-copy-the-same-user-information-with-different-ids)): Query 2 is about 30% faster in our 300K rows test case, but still in the painfully slow level.

```
INSERT INTO OUTPUT (id, name, score)
SELECT id, name, score
FROM MAIN;

INSERT INTO OUTPUT (id, name, score)
SELECT d.new_id, c.name, c.score
FROM MAIN AS c
JOIN SUB AS d ON c.id = d.id;
```

Comment: avoid union like the plague

Comment: `ALTER TABLE \`SUB\` ADD INDEX id_index (\`id\`)` should speed your join.  By the way, why is the mapping in `SUB` not unique?  It looks like you're going to double your number of rows with your `JOIN`.